# Bootstrap 4 Card Header on left side

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="row">

  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="card bg-light mb-3" style="max-width: 18rem;">
      <div class="card-header">Logo</div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Light card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

The above code displays:

```
+-----------+
| Logo      |
+-----------+
|Content    |
+-----------+
```

But I need it as:

```
+------+-----------+
|Logo  | Content   |
+------+-----------+
|  Content         |
+------------------+
```

I need the Card Header on the left side. I am using the latest version of Bootstrap.

Comment: which is the content? `card-body` or `card-title` or `card-text`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Bootstrap grids to achieve this.
As per question raised in the comment, updating the snippet as per requirment

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <div class="card bg-light mb-3 col-6">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="card-header col-6 border">Logo</div>
      <div class="card-body col-6 border">
        <h5 class="card-title">Light card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body col-12 border">
        <h5 class="card-title">Light card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: and the third content?

Comment: @samu check it. Updated the snippet as per your layout

Comment: @samu apply `class="img-fluid"` to your image. It will automatically adjust

Comment: Header again moves on top when the screen is small. https://jsfiddle.net/dawxhLu6/1/

Comment: @samu Have a look at the updated snippet. Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wc1nbe8y/1/

Comment: @samu If it meets your requirement please accept the answer. Happy coding